# Transferring IDM Internet Download manager links

Tags: windows-xp, download

How can I view incomplete download links in IDM?

How would I transfer the links from one computer to another computer in IDM?

Comment: What do you mean by transfer links? Send over the text information?

Comment: You could try enabling a share, put a text file in links with it and download it from the other computer.

Comment: Or you can setup an FTP server, or Web server, many possibilities

Answer (score 1):

You can import a list of downloads to Internet Download Manager. Pick "File->Import->From text file" menu item from IDM main menu.

IDM will find all Internet links (URLs) in an imported file and show them in a list. You can delete or edit these links before importing them to Internet Download Manager.

You can import a list of downloads to Internet Download Manager. Pick "File->Export->" menu item from IDM main menu.